# What would happen if a gravitational wave hit me?

Tags: gravitational-waves, technology

What would happen if a gravitational wave hits me? Will it affect me or will something else happen?

Comment: Watch out!  I think there's one coming right now.

Comment: Related and/or duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/207535/ and http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/237281/

Comment: @WillO haha, now that it's been like 5 years since I asked this question and have gained much more knowledge of physics than at that time, I find both your comment and the question funny XD

Comment: @aymusbond:  :) :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All depends on its intensity. In fact it will strech you in one direction and press you in the other. In 99,9999..% of cases you will never notice that it is passed trhough you since it interacts with you very very very very weakly. Actually right now in this very moment thousands or even billions of gravitational waves reached you coming from all over the universe.
So in short - it would happen almost nothing.