# LIGO event - energies involved?

Tags: general-relativity, ligo

So, we have two Black Holes merging shortly after LIGO turns on after the upgrade. Some questions:

a) How lucky was it to see this event? What are the expected rate of occurrence?

b) Was this event energetic enough to be seen on the original LIGO?

c) How close to the event would you have to be to actually feel the gravitation wave physically?

Comment: see this blog discussion http://motls.blogspot.gr/2016/02/ligo-discovers-black-hole-merger-12.html

Comment: a) [The Rate of Binary Black Hole Mergers Inferred from Advanced LIGO Observations Surrounding GW150914](http://arxiv.org/abs/1602.03842)

Comment: (b) http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/236145/could-old-ligo-have-detected-gw150914

Comment: (a) http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/236028/how-would-we-estimate-ahead-of-time-the-chances-of-ligo-spotting-black-holes and http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/238527/what-was-the-rate-of-black-hole-black-hole-mergers-expected-to-be-detected-by

Comment: (c) http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/168274/how-close-would-you-have-to-be-to-the-merger-of-two-black-holes-for-the-effects

Comment: I think this question suffered from having an obscure title and asking three (good) quedtions, rather than one. As it is, this seems to be well covered by other, sometimes later, questions and answers.

Answer (score 1):

The occurance rate expected in the Universe is about 4 times per hour, of which, LIGO thinks we can detect 4 or so per year. So it was probably lucky to see the event a few days after turning the detector on, but not too good to be true. The event would not have been seen in the original LIGO, The strain peaks at $10^{-21}$ which is detectable by pre-advanced LIGO, but the rest of the shape of the wave would not have been. The energy of the event has *a lot* of uncertainty, but about 3 solar masses emitted in gravitational wave energy.