# Could (old) LIGO have detected GW150914?

Tags: gravitational-waves, interferometry, ligo

The merging black hole binary system GW150914 was detected in only 16 days of aLIGO data at a signal level that appears to be well above the detection threshold at around 5 sigma. There are no further events between 4 and 5 sigma in the same data.

Could this event have been detected by previous LIGO/VIRGO incarnations which observed for much longer, albeit with lower sensitivity? If so, does this indicate that the aLIGO team have struck lucky and that this is a comparatively rare event that may not be repeated for many years?

EDIT: The answers I have agree that LIGO couldn't have seen it, but don't yet completely explain why. GW150914 had a strain that rose from a few $10^{-22}$ to $10^{-21}$ over about 0.2 seconds. This appears to make the *characteristic strain* maybe a few $10^{-22}$ Hz$^{-1/2}$ and thus would appear from the published sensitivity curves to lie above original LIGO's detection sensitivity at frequencies of $\sim 100$ Hz. Is my estimate of the characteristic strain way off?

Comment: Did they say why they picked this particular data set? Can we speculate that there are other datasets from the run that contain more events that will be published later?

Comment: This just lets me think how unlucky it would have been, if the ligo would have been offline due to its improvement while this event had been occured... >.<'

Comment: @CuriousOne Possibly just because they had to pick a stretch of data so they could start writing the paper.  Still, I look forward to seeing what the next 88 days of data contained :)

Comment: @WillVousden: I am simply asking if there are any rumors about what else is in the rest of the data... :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne It had crossed my mind as well... I wish I knew!  I left the collaboration just after the detection :-(

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To expand on HDE's answer, initial LIGO indeed wouldn't have detected GW150914, but it's not quite as simple as the peak strain being below the curve in the sensitivity plot: the integration time also matters.

These plots can be misleading; the curves they show *don't* represent a minimum detectable strain.  **Indeed, the units on the y-axis of these plots are $\mathrm{Hz}^{-1/2}$, while the GW strain is dimensionless, so you can't actually compare them!**  It's entirely possible to detect a signal that peaks well below the noise curve, as long as it's in-band for sufficiently long.

The curves that you see describing LIGO detector sensitivities conventionally show the **amplitude spectral density** of the detector noise.  Meanwhile, the threshold for a detection is determined by the **signal-to-noise ratio** (SNR) from [matched (Wiener) filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matched_filter).  Assuming we know the form of the signal $h$ in advance (see caveats below), this is defined in terms of the noise-weighted inner product of $h$ with itself:
$$
\mathrm{SNR}^2 = \left<h,h\right> \equiv \int_0^\infty \frac{4|\tilde{h}(f)|^2}{S_n(f)}\,\mathrm{d}f
$$
where $S_n(f)$ is the **noise power spectral density** (i.e., the *square* of what's shown in the sensitivity plots).  The SNR therefore depends on the spectral composition of the signal and its overlap with the detector bandwidth.

If you imagine this in the time domain (Parseval's theorem), the (squared) SNR actually accumulates in proportion to the number of cycles the waveform spends in-band.  For a monochromatic source, this is proportional to the integration time.  For example, if $\tilde{h}(f) = \delta(f-f_0)h_0$ and, without loss, the noise PSD is a constant $S_n(f_0)$, then the SNR is given by:
$$
\mathrm{SNR}^2 = \frac{2}{S_n}\int_{-\infty}^\infty|\tilde{h}(f)|^2\,\mathrm{d}f = \frac{2}{S_n}\int_{-\infty}^\infty|h(t)|^2\,\mathrm{d}t
$$
Therefore, since $|h(t)| = h_0$, for a finite observation window $T$, the SNR scales with $\sqrt{T}$:
$$
\mathrm{SNR} = \sqrt{\frac{2T}{S_n}}h_0
$$

So, let's approximate GW150914 as a monochromatic source.  Reading off the plots in the detection paper, let's say it has a average frequency of $f_0 \approx 60 \ \mathrm{Hz}$, an amplitude of $h_0\approx 5\times10^{-22}$, and a duration of $T \approx 0.2\ \mathrm{s}$.  Then, reading off a strain ASD of $\sqrt{S_n(f_0)} \approx  10^{-22}$ for initial LIGO, we'd get an SNR of around 3, which doesn't meet the standard detection threshold of 8 (also, see the caveats below).

There's a much more complete discussion of detector sensitivity curves [in this paper](http://www.ast.cam.ac.uk/~cjm96/noise_curve.pdf); it's worth a read!  A more useful quantity, described in this paper, is the **characteristic strain**, which attempts to account for the frequency evolution of an inspiral signal such as GW150914, to ease comparison between detector sensitivity and strain amplitude.

---

**Caveats:** in practice, it's more complicated than the matched filter model, since the detector noise is annoyingly non-stationary and non-Gaussian.  There are more sophisticated search algorithms that use things like signal quality vetoes and $\chi^2$ discriminants that reject spurious responses of the matched filter.  There are also search algorithms that don't require *a priori* knowledge of the signal waveform and can detect unmodelled bursts.  It was actually this sort of generic search that detected GW150914; references are available in [the detection paper](http://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.116.061102).

Also note that the SNR defined above is the *optimal SNR* that you get if:

1. you filter the data stream with the exact signal that you're looking for, and
2. the noise realisation is zero.

Since the mean of the noise is zero, number 2 above is equivalent to taking the expectation of the SNR over all noise realisations.

In practice, we don't know the precise signal *a priori*, and some SNR is lost in the approximation.  For a candidate waveform $u$, the expected SNR (over all noise realisations) is then given by
$$
\mathrm{SNR} = \frac{\left<u,h\right>}{\|u\|}
$$

Comment: Right, to compare with the sensitivity plots you need to multiply the strain by the square root of the time the signal was observed for (roughly)?

Comment: @RobJeffries To the extent that the signal is approximately monochromatic, yes (and of course you must divide by the noise PSD at the signal's characteristic frequency).  That will give you an approximate SNR, which you can compare to with whatever threshold you've picked (conventionally 8) to determine whether the signal would be detected.

Comment: (For more complicated/broadband signals, you have to know the waveform $h(f)$ and do the integration above.)

Comment: Given that, then the strain of this event was a few $10^{-22}$ up to a peak of $10^{-21}$ seen over about 0.2 secs. So isn't that characteristic strain $>10^{-22}$ Hz$^{-1/2}$? In which case the sensitivity curves I've seen (see HDE226868's answer) suggest that original LIGO would have detected it. I'm guessing then that my estimate of the characteristic strain is too high by factors of a few - why?

Comment: @RobJeffries See my update for an example calculation of the SNR for GW150914 :)

Comment: I am accepting this, but note that the signal swept from 35 Hz to 150 Hz. It was strongest at highest frequencies. If you took the frequency to be 100 Hz, $h_0 \sim 7\times 10^{-22}$, $T=0.1$s and $\sqrt{S_n(f_0)} \sim 4\times 10^{-23}$, you get a SNR of 8. This seems quite close..., maybe too close to call a press conference? I bet that people are now poring over the old LIGO data to see if there are a population of events with SNR~8?

Comment: @RobJeffries I was really just trying to show that it's consistent with being undetectable by iLIGO.  The matched filtering description I gave defines the *optimal* SNR that would be recovered if the true waveform is known perfectly a priori, and making unrealistic assumptions about detector noise.  In reality, you tend only to have a crude approximation to the true waveform, which means you lose some of that optimal SNR, and, in the presence of realistic noise, the SNR alone isn't sufficient anyway.

Comment: @RobJeffries But you're right it wouldn't have been *that* far from being detectable with initial LIGO.  By any measure, this was an unusually loud signal, and we'd expect most detections to be much quieter than this.  [arXiv:1602.03842](http://arxiv.org/abs/1602.03842) has an extended discussion of this.

Comment: Isn't another way of thinking about it that the sensitivity (as defined by the ASD) has reduced by a factor of ~4 between current aLIGO and iLIGO, so for the same signal I guess the SNR is 24/4=6 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35796/discussion-between-will-vousden-and-rob-jeffries).

Answer (score 23):

I have a direct quote from [the website](https://www.advancedligo.mit.edu/):

> The event would not have registered in LIGO's first-generation detectors; the fact that it appeared with striking clarity in both L1 and H1 indicates the leap in detector performance that the Advanced LIGO program has produced.

This was a sensitivity issue: in most frequencies, Advanced LIGO is more strain-sensitive than LIGO [by a factor of 10](https://www.ligo.caltech.edu/page/about-aligo).

[Hild (2012)](http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.6277) gives an overview of first- and second- generation detectors, including this graph:

[image]

The detected wave had a peak strain of $\thicksim 10^{-21} ~\mathrm{1/\sqrt{\textrm{Hz}}}$ and was detected at frequencies between $35$ and $250~\textrm{Hz}.$ A portion of this *does* fall in the original LIGO sensitivity range. However, as Figure 3 of [the Advanced LIGO detection paper](http://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.116.061102) shows, most falls below it.

Regarding the odds of detection, [older estimates](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0264-9381/27/8/084006/pdf;jsessionid=00AFCD541625E3C533C93F5B30DC6B17.c4.iopscience.cld.iop.org) said that Advanced LIGO should be able to observe $\thicksim 40$ neutron star "inspiral events", and $\thicksim 30$ black hole binary events of the same type. This would be attributed in part to the noise reduction, making it easier to observe larger areas. [The group says that event rate detection would increase by 3000](https://www.advancedligo.mit.edu/summary.html) following the sensitivity upgrades.

Comment: Agreed original LIGO is a factor 4 less sensitive, but there were intermediate upgrades. I'd also like to know the quantitative details. It does look from published sensitivity curves that it might have been seen...

Comment: @RobJeffries I understand; I'm looking for the particulars.

Comment: @RobJeffries I don't have a reference on hand, but a LIGO person the other day said in a talk this event, which was SNR=24 by some measure, would have been SNR=3 or 4 in old LIGO iirc, below their threshold of 8 for reporting.

Comment: I think that strain number you quote is a bit tricky. The *peak* strain was $10^{-21}$, but the equivalent strain (which is on the y-axis of your plot) was more like $3\times 10^{-22}$.

Comment: I meant characteristic strain, not equivalent strain.

Comment: @HDE226868: Edited formatting. Check this; if you don't like, then you can rollback it.

Comment: @user36790 "aLIGO" isn't a typo; it's an abbreviation of "Advanced LIGO" :) I've suggested an edit to replace the abbreviations with their full names.

Comment: @Will Vousden: Didn't know that; accepted your suggested edit and replaced another `aligo` with `Advanced Ligo`; thanks.

Comment: OK, but accepting the curves above and a *characteristic* strain of a few $10^{-22}$, doesn't the plot in fact suggest that original LIGO would have seen it at $\sim 100$ Hz. This is basically my whole question. I know that aLIGO is more sensitive.

Comment: Can you also confirm that this is the *current* sensitivity of aLIGO. It looks more like the design sensitivity that will be eventually achieved. Other plots I have seen suggest a characteristic strain sensitivity of about $10^{-23}$ at 100 Hz. e.g https://christopherplberry.files.wordpress.com/2015/01/characteristic_strain.png

Comment: It is indeed the design sensitivity. aLIGO is not yet 10 times more sensitive than original LIGO.

Comment: *making it easier to observe larger areas* : how to observe a particular area with fixed arms ? with other interofometer setting ?

Answer (score 7):

Despite my hopes, it appears that old LIGO would not have detected GW150914.  Sigh...

From the [discovery announcement](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.116.061102) of GW150914, I created a facsimile of the measured strain signal:

[image: h(t)]

From that paper and also the [summary of Run 6 of original LIGO](http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.7314), in 2009-2010, I digitized amplitude spectral densities of the two:

[image]

From these inputs I calculated the characteristic strain and noise curves:

[image]

Integrating these up per the very helpful [reference](http://arxiv.org/abs/1408.0740) identified by Will Vousden, I calculate the following results for signal-to-noise ratio $\rho$ for a matched filter:

\begin{equation*}
   \begin{array}{lcccc}
     \text{detector}   & \rho & \chi_r^2 & \hat{\rho} & \hat{\rho_c} \\
     \text{aLIGO}      & 18.73 & 1.44  & 16.69      & 23.6   \\
     \text{LIGO run 6} &  4.88 & 1.44  &  4.35      &  6.2
   \end{array}
\end{equation*}

Here:

- $\rho$ is the calculated signal-to-noise ratio for the detector.
- the $\chi_r^2$ statistic measures how closely the signal matches the expected waveform template.  This value was not reported, that I could see; I have chosen it to get the correct final result for aLIGO, and then used the same value for LIGO Run 6.
- $\hat{\rho}$ penalizes $\rho$ based on the value of $\chi_r^2$.
- $\hat{\rho}_c$ accounts for the signal being observed by both LIGO detectors: the two signal-to-noise ratios are added in quadrature (so here the value is multiplied by $\sqrt{2}$.)

Since the Run 6 signal-to-noise ratio $\rho < 8$, it would have been very difficult to claim a detection: in this [review](http://arxiv.org/abs/1209.6533) of Run 6's search for massive black hole inspiral/merger signals, Figure 2 shows that signals with these values of $\rho$ and $\chi_r^2$ would be buried in noise events.

Curiously, that same review includes Figure 1, which appears to show a 60 total solar mass event being detectable out to about 470 Mpc (with favorable orientation), which would include most of the the reported distance range of $410_{-180}^{+160}$ Mpc.  I cannot explain the discrepancy.

Comment: Belated thanks for this. Yes it appears to be close, but not quite.

Comment: Some awesome work here!