# What effect would GW150914 have had over a much shorter distance?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gravitational-waves, estimation, ligo

In the wake of the recent news of the confirmation of the existence on gravitational waves, I was discussing gravitational waves with a friend, and he asked whether this could potentially lead to some kind of warp drive, and I pretty much immediately dismissed it. However, it got me thinking.

The gravitational waves detected by LIGO were from 2 black holes that merged and released of the order of 3 solar masses of gravitational energy (I apologise if I'm slightly butchering the science here, I'm no physicist), and it caused a "deflection" (again, please excuse, and feel free to correct, any technical ignorance on my part) of a fraction of the width of a proton.

The point of my question is this: if such an unimaginably large output of energy could cause such a tiny "deflection" at a distance of ~1.3 billion light years, what would something like LIGO (or perhaps something more like ESA's eLISA) observe at a distance of only 1 light year?

Comment: do you mean : "what is the dependency of the GW to the distance ? Is it something on 1/r , 1/r² or what else ?"

Comment: Yeah, I guess that was sort of what I was asking. The answer linked by @ACuriousMind tells me enough I think.

Answer (score 0):

possible answer....[How close would you have to be to the merger of two black holes, for the effects of gravitational waves to be detected without instruments?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/168274/102800)  ....As he explains, if somethings like that happens a the distance you suggest, we should not be worrying about the waves.

Comment: Please don't post a _link-only_ answer; in this context, it should rather be a comment and not an answer.

Comment: ok......but if was trivial, it would have been converted to a comment automatically right?

Comment: No. There is no such mechanism here.

Comment: That answer does help, but I don't think it fully answers my question. For starters, its talking about a distance a billion times closer and a black hole much smaller (I think).